# Global value to class const

Tags: php, global-variables, constants

Well, I have dealed with global and const values. Figure out something like this:

```
<?

global $foo;

class MyClass{

    const BAR = $foo;
...
```

Looks like this is not allowed, so I just want to know if is it valid code or is just a mistake in some assignation.

PS: I know that there are many ways to do what I am expecting, just want to discart this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const` expects a constant. `$foo` is a variable, not a constant.

It is clearly explained in the [PHP Class Constant Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php):

> The value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a property, a result of a mathematical operation, or a function call.

Comment: it has sence! could not be best explained. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use [define](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) function.
Globals are bad practice